# Is there a way to run CI checks without making a commit in the pr?

Tags: learning

This on its own would not make much sense, but this could be useful when having a companion PR to check whether the CI for the companion passes.

Comment: There are A LOT of checks. Question is if you actually want to run those on your PC instead of utilizing the CI.

Comment: There should be a button for this in the GitHub UI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67201761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Substrate question.

But here you go https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow.